# Write up work means?

Tags: ielts, listening

I have just finished a practice test for Ielts, and I looked at the key. There is a question in listening part asking about what the speaker said for a course requirement.

The question number 27 is what I want to ask about. It requires NO MORE THAN THREE WORDS.

[image]

The speaker said:

*"Yes, that’s right. And then you have to **`write up your piece of work`** and give it to the lecturer to be marked."*

And when I was hearing the phrase **"write up"** followed by **"and give it to the lecturer to be marked"**, I thought it had the same meaning as **"finish your work (get it done)"**. So I filled **"Finish your work"** in the blank.

But it appeared **"Write up work"** is in the key for this question

Are they replaceable in this case?

Comment: If the 'work' is writing, then you can sort of argue that writing up is equivalent to doing the work. Otherwise, it's talking about creating the *report* related to the work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Write up' and 'finish up' have very different meanings.

To write up means to give a written summary of some event, or even to write the event rather like a story.

> I carried out the experiments, then wrote up the results.
>
> I like to write up my experiences in my diary after every trip.

When we hear 'write up' we know that we are going to hear some kind of summary.

To finish up, as the verb suggests, means that we need to complete an action that has already begun. This could be any action, not just writing, but is particularly used for things that we do.

> "Finish up your breakfast, you are going to be late."
>
> I finished up the remaining exercises, and then went and watched TV.